# processing text using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to process a csv file using awk. I have five rows in my csv file. I want my column 1 & column 3 combined to be unique. Using awk I wrote

`awk -F "," '{print $1,",",$2,","$3,",",$4,",",$5}' A.csv|sort|uniq >B.csv`

What this code does is to have a unique row with 1 to 5 rows combined. I want my other columns to be in final csv file but sorted and uniq only by 1st and 3rd columns.

Comment: please provide example input and desired output

Comment: When you say combined based on a unique key does that mean the new combined row could have 6 elements in addition to the keys? If so, sounds like you picked the wrong tool. A Perl script using a hash table would work out nicely in this case.

Comment: @tawman awk supports associative arrays just fine. But until the OP actually provides something concrete that we can see, I doubt anybody is going to expend the time writing something up when we can only speculate what the OP really wants.

Comment: Agreed, awk has quite an in-depth language that rarely the unix user dives into that far. I did once a long time ago, but easier to use the tools you know. I did not mean to insult the power of awk!

Comment: You don't have to use all those quoted commas, by the way. `awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=, filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you want to keep at least one of the duplicate lines

```
$ more file
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 4 6 3 5 8
1 43 3 6 5 10
2 3 4 4 4 4

$ awk '(!($1$3 in u)){u[$1$3]=$0}END{for(i in u ) print u[i]}' file
7 4 6 3 5 8
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 4 4 4
```

If you don't want to keep duplicate lines

```
$ awk '($1$3 in u){delete u[$1$3];next}{u[$1$3]=$0}END{for(i in u ) print u[i]}' file
7 4 6 3 5 8
2 3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: @ghostdog...could you please explein the solution here